# drop down list based on selection of another drop down

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. I want to populate the drop down list from the **model**

```
 <%= collection_select(nil, :entity_id,  @entity,  :id, :name,
 {:prompt   => "Select an Entity"}, {:id => 'entity_select'}) %>
```

based on another drop down list

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :project_id,  @projects,  :id, :name,
 {:prompt   => "Select a Project"} %>
```

On selection of projects the corresponding entities needs to be displayed in a drop down but I get all the entities in the entities table being displayed. I have no idea of Ajax . Is there any other simple way?

Comment: It's going to require some javascript one way or another...  either ajax to question the server for the new related values, or else a javascript structure in code that holds the values for each key from the previous select.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use `grouped_collection_select` for this particular case. 
More details are in [Rails API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select)

Also consider watching detailed [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) by Ryan Bates

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
collection_select(nil, :entity_id, Entity.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select an Entity")
```